# OSX: ssh-agent caching passphrases....but when cleared?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, mac-osx, ssh-agent

I have a ssh RSA key in a client OSX 10.9.4. The SSH server is ubuntu. Everything works OK, but the problem is that my OSX ssh-agent seems to be caching the passphrases. The first time I ssh, it is asked. Next time, it is not, and I directly log in the server.

I am worried about security here. If someone steals my machine would have access to the server without entering any password...yeah, I still have my OSX user, but still.

So do you know when OSX ssh-agent asks again?

It seems I have the same question as: http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2007/11/28/securing_ssh_agent/

But I don't know how that applies to OSX 10.9.4

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a key's lifetime when you add it with [ssh-add(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh-add.1?query=ssh-add&sec=1):

```
-t life
         Set a maximum lifetime when adding identities to an agent.  The
         lifetime may be specified in seconds or in a time format speci‐
         fied in sshd_config(5).
```

e.g.

```
ssh-add   -t 3600  ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

will make the agent forget this key after 1h.

If your keys get auto-loaded, you can either try to find where that happens (.bashrc, .bash_profile, /etc/profile, ...) and change the ssh-add parameters there; Or remove the keys from the agent (`ssh-add -D`) and re-add with a lifetime as above.

Alternatively, if you want your agent to *always* forget keys after say 1h, you could alter the service definition as described e.g. [here](http://tim.vanwerkhoven.org/post/2011/11/17/OSX-launchd-and-launchctl-issues). But that seems to [not work for everyone](https://superuser.com/questions/580584/launchd-not-launching-ssh-agent-after-plist-edit).

[I assume here that your OSX is also using OpenSSH for SSH client and agent, just like that old OSX 10.6.8 i have access to. If your OSX is using something else by now, then this answer might not apply]

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful. I ended doing the first step from [http://tim.vanwerkhoven.org/post/2011/11/17/OSX-launchd-and-launchctl-issues]  thank you very much